# Python read only specific columns excel sheet by column name

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel sheet contains many columns.

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
  1    2     A
  2    2     B
  3    2     B
```

I am using pandas read_excel and use "usecols" to read a column by its index. Just wondering if there is any way to read those columns by their name instead? For instance, in this example Col2 and Col3?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, usecols="A,C")
```

Comment: `usecols = ['Col2','Col3']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Col2` and `Col3` the you can use the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, usecols = ['Col2','Col3'])
```

or you can use this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name)[['Col2', 'Col3']]
```

Comment: if `usecols` is to specify column names, then when to use `names`? [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html): `List of column names to use.`

Comment: @LeiYang I think both can be used. Maybe `names` would be better. The doc for use `usecols` with a list of strings says, "If list of string, then indicates list of column names to be parsed."